# Size-classes and constraints with buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I hope someone can help here as I've been reading and watching a lot about size classes as I've just started work on first app using size classes.I thought I'd got the idea but having a slight issue.

I've got a view with 10 buttons in it. I want the buttons to re-size to fill the desired screen but as you can see from the screenshot below all I'm left with is loads of white space on the bigger views?

I've set constraints to the view and to each other so I though Aspect Ratio should solve it....No, all I get them is one huge buttons and the rest stay the same!

I've researched a lot so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Please see this image of the issue.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: A mockup of the result you're expecting would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pin the top of the top button to its superview.
2. Pin the bottom of the bottom button to its superview.
3. Assign a fixed vertical space between each button.
4. Select all the buttons and specify "Equal Height."

This should take care of your vertical constraints, and the button heights will equally expand or contract, depending on the screen height.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give it a try tomorrow. I clearly didn't have the full grasp! Thanks again.

Comment: Just tried this @PetahChristian and it works great, thank you once again!

Comment: Great!  It will be even easier to do this in iOS 9, using `UIStackView`.